# Laravel fallback route always returning view instead of Json response

Tags: laravel

Building a REST API with Laravel. I would like to return a JSON message when a client hits a non-existing route.

I have the following api.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', 'ListingController@getListingsAll')->name('all');


// No Authenticated Routes

Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login')->name('login');
    Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register')->name('register');
});

// Authenticated Routes

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    //Auth functions
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
    });

    //Listings

    Route::get('listings/user', 'ListingController@getListingsPerUser')->name('listings.user');
    Route::get('listings/all', 'ListingController@getListingsAll')->name('listings.all');
    ...
    ...
});


Route::fallback(function () {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Found!'], 404);
});
```

Whenever I execute a REST call to `http://localhost:8000/foo` or `http://localhost:8000/api/foo` etc... it returns a 404 Not found Blade view instead of a JSON response.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to implement this in the Exception Handler

`App\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            return response(['status' => 'Not Found'], 404);
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. In fact, I tried it before but I forgot to add the `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;`. Without it, things don't work. Thanks for your help!